# mysql dynamic crosstab with date as columns

Tags: mysql, database, date, pivot, crosstab

Here is my problem, lets say I have a data base table that looks like this:

tbl: incoming

```
ID | Type  | cdate
 1 | Type1 | 2014-07-01 6:00:00
 1 | Type2 | 2014-07-02 6:00:00
 1 | Type1 | 2014-07-03 6:00:00
 1 | Type3 | 2014-07-04 6:00:00
 1 | Type2 | 2014-07-04 6:00:00
```

I want a query that will display the data with the dates as a column:

```
Type  |  7-1  |  7-2  |  7-3  |  7-4  
Type1 |  1    |  0    |   1   |  0
Type2 |  0    |  1    |   0   |  1
Type3 |  0    |  0    |   0   |  1
```

The SQL code I have is:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when date_format(cdate, '%m-%d') = ''',
      date_format(cdate, '%m-%d'),
      ''' then 1 end) AS ',
      replace(cdate, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from incoming WHERE cdate BETWEEN '2014-07-01 5:00:00' AND '2014-07-04 5:00:00';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT type, ', @sql, ' from incoming group by type');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I receive a sql syntax error when I run the script. Can anyone help me figure out what is broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes in your expression.
Also, create a more simple alias for your columns, and enclose it in backticks (just in case).

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when date_format(cdate, \'%m-%d\') = \'', -- Escape quotes here
      date_format(cdate, '%m-%d'),                          -- (I prefer to use
      '\' then 1 end) AS ',                                 -- \' instead of ''')
      '`', date_format(cdate, '%Y%m%d'), '`' -- Create a simpler alias for 
                                             -- columns here, and don't forget 
                                             -- to enclose the alias in 
                                             -- back-ticks (`)
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from incoming;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT type, ', @sql, ' from incoming group by type');

select @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Check [example in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d696/6)

Comment: Thank You this worked perfectly. I been trying to figure out why it wasn't working for days now.

Comment: @Mike2414 Happy to help. A simple way to check if your `@sql` is correct is to simply show its value: `select @sql`. Also, it is a good idea to always enclose the column aliases between backticks

Comment: @Barranka, could you help me with my exact same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047877/mysql-cross-tab-query-that-displays-current-week-plus-past-12-weeks-dynamically