# MySQL Cross-tab query that displays Current Week, plus Past 12 Weeks Dynamically

Tags: mysql

I have a query that counts all tickets by weeks, but I need to convert it to a dynamic two-row report that moves the week-beginning dates to columns?

Here is what I'm trying to get it to do..
[image]

Here is my query:

```
SELECT td_type, FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(ttDate) -MOD(TO_DAYS(ttDate) -2, 7)) AS week_beginning,
   DATE_ADD( DATE(ttDate), INTERVAL (8 - DAYOFWEEK(ttDate)) DAY) week_ending,
   count(*)
FROM v_all_tickets
WHERE extract(year from ttDate) = '2018' AND ttCategory IN ('TT')
GROUP BY td_type, FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(ttDate) -MOD(TO_DAYS(ttDate) -2, 7))
ORDER BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(ttDate) -MOD(TO_DAYS(ttDate) -2, 7)) DESC, td_type
```

It displays the weeks & counts down the page, for two groups:
[image]

When I try this statement:

```
SET @sql_dynamic = (
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'COUNT( IF(MONTH(ttDate) = '
            , FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(ttDate) -MOD(TO_DAYS(ttDate) -2, 7))
            , ', ttNum,0) ) AS mo_'
            , MONTH(ttDate)
        )
    )
FROM v_all_tickets WHERE extract(year from ttDate) = '2018' AND ttCategory IN ('TT') AND td_type IN ('Fiber','Legacy')
);

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT td_type, ', 
          @sql_dynamic, ' 
       FROM v_all_tickets 
       GROUP BY td_type WITH ROLLUP'
   );

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I get the following results:
[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong in my statement above?

UPDATE: Here is my updated query thanks to Uueerdo. This gives me the weekly calculation MANUALLY, but how do I fix the Statement above to do it DYNAMICALLY? :
[image]

Comment: COUNT adds 1 for any non-null value it encounters, so using `0` in your "else" still increases the count. If you are trying to total numeric values, use SUM; if you're actually trying to count, try `COUNT(IF(something, 1, null))`

Comment: Uueerdo, Thanks for the guidance on the COUNT statement.. I've updated that part and now have the correct counts doing it manually.. but how do I fix the Statement to do it "Dynamically"?

Comment: Please add a data sample to.your question, or a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Create a temp table with the columns you need, and try the pivot on that temp table

Comment: Here is my sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d103/2/1

Comment: This sqfiddle runs fine w/o any errors but returns no records? Any ideas why?
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fda9b/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct MySQL Statement was:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_results;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_results AS
SELECT td_type, FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(ttDate) -MOD(TO_DAYS(ttDate) -2, 7)) AS ttDate, ttCategory, ttNum, Count(ttNum) tickets
FROM v_closed_tickets
WHERE extract(year from ttDate) = '2018' AND ttCategory IN ('TT')
GROUP BY td_type, ttDate
ORDER BY td_type, ttDate ASC;

SELECT CONCAT('
SELECT td_type, ',tickets_by_dates,'
FROM tmp_results
GROUP BY td_type WITH ROLLUP
'
)
INTO @query
FROM
(
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN ttDate=''',actual_date,''' THEN tickets END), ''-'') AS "',col_name,'"')) tickets_by_dates
FROM (
SELECT actual_date, DATE_FORMAT(actual_date,'%m/%d') AS col_name
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ttDate AS actual_date FROM tmp_results) AS dates
) dates_with_col_names
) result;

PREPARE statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

This produced the correct output as follows:
[image]

Thanks to all who helped!